# Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, command-line-interface

I have this error repeating continuously in my program.

I have tried the following:

1. Restart Visual Studio
2. Clean and Rebuild Solution

When I step through the code line by line, it stops leaving me totally confused at a method call:

```
GenerateWorksheetPart1Content(WorksheetPart worksheetPart1)
```

I don't understand why it stops there. The parameter is not null at the point. What could be causing the error?

Comment: Check for the added references and external libraries.

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN - InvalidProgramException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidprogramexception.aspx)

Excerpt:

`The exception that is thrown when a program contains invalid Microsoft 
intermediate language (MSIL) or metadata. Generally this indicates
a bug in the compiler that generated the program.`

This is happening as you step through the code because as your method is called it is being JIT compiled. If the compilation by the JITer is invalid, this exception will be thrown at this point.

Comment: Is it just me or do I get this error frequently when dealing with VB.NET code rather than C#? To me it looks like the VB.NET JIT is trashy... also needs really long to change a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Try following-

1) Delete temporary asp.net files from `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files`
2) Recompile the assemblies and update the corresponding referenses

Comment: That folder doesn't exist on my machine. The only folders at that location are "CONFIG" and "en" and anyway, I'm running ASP.NET Core 2.2