# Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program from Build Server, but not local VS2015 compile

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nant

First of all, thank you everybody for all you do for the community, I have found so many answers on this forum.

I am working on a Large winforms project that connects to a WCF server.
I am using Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 4.0.

As of this morning, when I do a build on our Nant Build Server (Windows Server 2003), and update my test application I am getting a "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program" once I click my Login button.

So the App Loads, the Main Form loads but this is thrown when I click Login.

However, if I build and debug the App locally, I am able to run the application just fine.

Unfortunately, I did not setup the Build server as I have come in after the Architects and am in charge of Maintenance and Updating.

The differences between the last build that worked and the current build are very minute.

I removed a PictureBox, renamed a Tab, Updated some DLLs that link to the Server after adding another Server Call.

I know the Server is working correctly because I am pointing to the same server when I am Debugging or running the Downloaded App.

Thank you so much, and I will be happy to provide you with any more information!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow -- #SOReadyToHelp.  Have you seen this MSDN KB article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312544

Comment: This details the exact scenario, thank you!

Comment: David Tansey:  Where can I get my hands on cordbg?  I've googled for it and searched my machine for it, no luck in finding it.

Running Windows 10, and Visual Studio 2015, also have 2010, 2012 installed.

Comment: I think this post from over on SuperUser should help you get going with `CorDbg` http://superuser.com/questions/983305/where-is-cordbg

Comment: Thank you for the Help!  
The response from this article helped me out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563299/invalidprogramexception-common-language-runtime-detected-an-invalid-program

I disabled optimization in one of our projects and it works now.