# CkFinder error for asp

Tags: asp.net, ckfinder

I am getting error related to CkFinder. I am getting error related to connector. Error comes when application try to access this "/ckfinder/connector?command=Init&lang=en" using Ckfinder.js file.
Please see the attached screenshot for same.

[CkFinder Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jyh9.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InvalidProgramException / Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563299/invalidprogramexception-common-language-runtime-detected-an-invalid-program)

Comment: Thanks for replying but this solution didn't helped. Have you ever worked using CkFinder?

Comment: Could you please provide more details about this issue, with some code examples? Please also have a look at: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/quickstart.html

Comment: Zaak, issue has been resolved. It was related to some other dll that was raising this error. 
Thanks, I had already gone through the link which you had shared.