# Newtonsoft JSON deserialization not working while using ConfuserEx

Tags: c#, json, json.net, confuserex

I have a JSON class like this:

```
public class UpdateCheck
{
    public bool UpdatesAvailable { get; set; }
    public string LinkOfNewVersion { get; set; }
}
```

But the value of `UpdatesAvailable` and `LinkOfNewVersion` are null when I confuse my assembly using ConfuserEx :/

I've tried all the following:

Adding the `[Obfuscation(Exclude = false, Feature = "-rename")]` attribute above my JSON class:

```
[Obfuscation(Exclude = false, Feature = "-rename")]
public class UpdateCheck
{
    public bool UpdatesAvailable { get; set; }
    public string LinkOfNewVersion { get; set; }
}
```

---

Adding the `[Serializable]` attribute above my JSON class:

```
[Serializable]
public class UpdateCheck
{
    public bool UpdatesAvailable { get; set; }
    public string LinkOfNewVersion { get; set; }
}
```

---

Adding both attributes above my JSON class:

```
[Serializable]
[Obfuscation(Exclude = false, Feature = "-rename")]
public class UpdateCheck
{
    public bool UpdatesAvailable { get; set; }
    public string LinkOfNewVersion { get; set; }
}
```

---

But all what I've tried failed :/

My obfuscation properties:

```
  <rule pattern="true" preset="maximum" inherit="false">
    <protection id="anti ildasm" />
    <protection id="anti tamper" />
    <protection id="constants" />
    <protection id="ctrl flow" />
    <protection id="anti dump" />
    <protection id="anti debug" />
    <protection id="invalid metadata" />
    <protection id="ref proxy" />
    <protection id="resources" />
    <protection id="typescramble" />
    <protection id="rename" />
  </rule>
```

And when I remove the "rename" protection from my ConfuserEx config file, my assembly crashes like that:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: any updates after two years?

Comment: that may help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.obfuscationattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0

Comment: why not just use `[ObfuscationAttribute(Exclude=true, ApplyToMembers=true)]` for class?

Answer (score 5):

Try using `JsonProperty` attributes to set the field names to their fixed values:

```
public class UpdateCheck
{
    [JsonProperty("UpdatesAvailable")]
    public bool UpdatesAvailable { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LinkOfNewVersion")]
    public string LinkOfNewVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! But unfortunately, I am still getting this crash: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTVtz.png

Comment: Based on the error you are getting, see if this Q&A helps: [InvalidProgramException / Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23563299/1220550)

Comment: I've disabled the `typescramble` feature of ConfuserEx and now the crash disappeared. Also the JSON is working now! I will accept this solution once I can :-)

Comment: @gave How to disabled the typescramble, I don't see this option at Setting tab

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically remove "name" & "typescramble" options. Using any preset above "None" includes "name" which is the main issue. I use maximum Preset without these two with no issues regarding Json.