# Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program in a .NET 6 API?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, invalidprogramexception

I am using .net6, Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web, with MVC and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 6.0.0.
The exception is caused by Microsoft classes and there is nothing to debug.
On the API side, the Error occurs in my Middleware class while trying to invoke the request:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method93(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
   at API.ErrorHandler.ErrorHandlingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in ..\API\src\API\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs
```

Main .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\GatewayApi.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Asp.Versioning.Http" Version="6.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NodaTime" Version="3.1.9" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    Many project references here
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

project referencing it:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>API</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>API</PackageId>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
    <BuildServerSideRenderer>false</BuildServerSideRenderer>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.NpgSql" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.1.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Datadog.Trace" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentFTP" Version="46.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks" Version="6.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore" Version="13.18.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.Core" Version="13.18.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore" Version="13.18.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="prometheus-net.AspNetCore" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="prometheus-net.DotNetRuntime" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="6.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Compression" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XmlSerializer" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XPath.XDocument" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\GatewayApi.Api\GatewayApi.Api.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="configs\appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BuildSpa" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build-prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build-prod:ssr" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />
    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles-&gt;'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The intresting thing about this is that it will process 2 requests to this endpoint before defaulting the to InvalidProgramException.

I tried reproducing the problem on a Dockerimage, debugging locally, and using tools (such as gitlab/kubernetes) to build and run the project in a different environment to see if it is maybe a problem with my local environment.

I also updated all nugets, made sure all the versions match in the solution, nothing is deprecated or is made of old frameworks.

Neither helped me get closer to a solution.

I am hoping someone helps me get to a point where this exception would not occur anymore.

EDIT:

- Added .csproj file and .csproj file of the project that references it

Comment: Can you please post the full [mre] somewhere (like github)? If this is not possible - please post at least .csproj file.

Comment: Had you taken a look at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73466954/7450780) ,seems to point to an issue he encountered with datadog tracer .

Comment: @DenisMicheal.k Completely removing Datadog's Nuget from the project and removing all of its implementations did not help.